# Ошибка при выполнении SOAP запроса

Tags: delphi, soap

Есть wsdl-схема SOAP сервера. Пытаюсь выполнить запрос на этот сервер. Выдает ошибку: *"Для документа XML должен существовать документ более высокого уровня"*.

Каким либо образом возможно посмотреть XML запроса, который отправляется на SOAP сервер?

Comment: Работаете через THTTPRIO? Какая версия Delphi?

Comment: На всё, что отправляется по сети, можно посмотреть fiddler-ом или wireshark-ом.

Comment: Работаю при помощи API-функций сервера. Delphi xe7.

Comment: `Работаю при помощи API-функций сервера` - конкретнее, пожалуйста. Какие компоненты / классы / модули используете для вызова API-функций сервера? И как сказал zed - если посмотреть запрос необходимо разово, то действительно проще использовать wireshark. Если же нужно логировать запросы, то нужны детали, как именно обращаетесь к серверу.

Comment: Спасибо, Zed. Твой комментарий помог разобраться, что же я не так отправляю. На данный момент осталась следующая проблема: при импортировании кода SOAP сервера, есть функция function  AttrSearch(const arg0: ArrayOfanyType; const arg1: string; const arg2: Integer): DocListInfo; stdcall;. Где ArrayOfAnyType : Array of String; я использую данную функцию 
Но она некорректно формирует XML вместо xsi:type = ns1:ArrayOfanyType Формируется xsi:type = "SOAP-ENC:Array". Как правильно использовать данный тип?